# What is the equivalent hardware circuit to this code?

Tags: verilog, addition, system-verilog, sequential, circuit

What does this code say? How do i interpret its circuit?

```
module add(input logic clock, output logic[7:0] f);
    logic[7:0] a, b, c;
    always_ff @(posedge clock)
    begin
    a <= b + c;
    b = c + a;
    c = a + b;
    end
    assign f = c;
    endmodule
```

Comment: don't mix blocking and unblocking assignments this way. you might end up with simulation/synthesis mismatch and/or races in simulation.

Comment: I thought that was the point of the question

Comment: If i take the initial values of a = 11011100, b = 00110011 and c = 10101010, then what would be the final values a,b,c and f? I'm not able to understand how I'm supposed to do the addition because both blocking and non-blocking statements have been used. I also want to know what circuit elements would be used to make this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

You should interpret this code the same as

```
module add(input logic clock, output logic[7:0] f);
  logic[7:0] a, b;
  always_ff @(posedge clock)
    a <= b + f;
  always_ff @(posedge clock)
    b <= f + a;
  always_ff @(posedge clock)
    f <= a + b;
 endmodule
```

This is logically equivalent to what you wrote, but gives predictable simulation results for any code that samples the output `f` on the `posedge clock`

Comment: What would the circuit look like?

Comment: I do not thing that this is equivalent. it will have different results for `c/f` and might cause sim/synt mismatch.

Comment: @MeganWinchester I do not have tools set up to draw schematics. I thought you were just curious about the mix of blocking and non-blocking assignments, A *real* circuit would require a reset.

Comment: @Serge By itself, there is no differences in result for `c/f` There is only a possibility of simulation difference when f is used in the rest of the design do to races